# How to set background image of any UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, constraints

I am trying to set a background image of my view container but issue is my UITableView Cell are of dynamic height and I want to control there height with respect of their content not according to image. 
How should I do that ??? here's what I am using in storyboard.

[image: These are my constraints]

[image: Hierarchy of my Views]

Now, issue is I didn't give any height or width constraint to main image as I said cells should respect their contents, therefore image expands or shrinks according to its own size.

**What I have already tried,**

1. Tried to give Priority to image constraints in every possible way.
2. Tried app background.color pattern method (this will repeat image multiple times.)

**What I want to do actually ?**

[image]

These cells have a image as background and some content. 
**Please Note that, content can be change, cells are dynamic.**

**Problem I am facing is,**
Image does not sets well, some times it comes on half portion of entire cell or sometimes it overlaps on to next cell. Image expands cells and thus cells adjust their heights according to image size, not according to content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hows it working now? Does the cell height dynamically works well for the text contents? Currently i don't understand what you struggled with :-[

Comment: I have updated my question, please check now

Comment: @Najam you have to count height as per your all labels height.

Comment: I was also thinking about it, there is no other way around ? @VDPurohit

Comment: Which label is to be dynamic? Label1(Loc1 -- Loc2 -- Loc3) or the Label2(Green Route)? Can you uploaded the screen with issue

Comment: @Najam please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Hello using below code you find the of label:-

```
let currentSource = "your label text"
let size = CGSize(width: screenWidth - 24, height: 0)
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font :  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)]
let estimatedFrame = NSString(string:    currentSource.text).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
```

using this code you got the height of label after find each of label's height and also add distance between label then then return in heightForRowAt delegate method(e.g. return estimatedFrame.height + "distance of each label(40)")

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Please take look on this GitHub repo (screenshot in the repo README):

https://github.com/tony42/TestTableCellBackground

Does this look like what you need?

I'm not exactly sure what you did wrong - so, I started over with an empty project. For me, the trick was to set the "compression resistance" of the image to "low" (250). It was a nice exercise :-)